# setting image in a specific place in container

Tags: css, image, position, image-resizing

i would like ti know how to set an image in a set place every time and set the size to a specific size. this is what i have but its not working i still get a large image and the images show up all over the container. i have tried changing the style to image tag but i still get the same problem can someone please help me ?

```
<div id="fotos" class="bananas"   style="position: absolute;top: 100px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your image `display:block;` and then specify `width` for them. You can do it in px as well as in %.

As for the set place. If you use `position:absolute;` on the image then it would not set it's position relative to `.bananas`, because you have specified `position:absolute` for `.bananas`.

You'd have to change `.bananas` to `position:relative;`. See the example below.

```css
.bananas{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
  height:160px;
  width:100%;
}
.bananas img{
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 30px;
}
#imgdisplay1{
  left:10px;
}
#imgdisplay2{
  left:170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fotos" class="bananas" >
  <img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay1" src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg"/>
  <img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay2" src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: what would the position be when i upload multiple images and have them display all in the same exact place every time im doing draggable. right now everytime i upload an image the image uploads underneath each of the earlier images and it disapears after 4 uploads

Comment: okay, the thing with absolute is that it removes that element from normal content flow.  if first image has `left:10px` then second should have `left:160px;` or more. I have updated my example for that.

Comment: Using absolute in dynamic content condition may be a bad thing. Use absolute when you know that your content will not change.

Comment: i appreciate all your time that you spent explaining this to me. thank you for the great answer.

Comment: Absolute is what im using and its still uploading at a different position on every upload

Answer (score 0):

> i would like ti know how to set an image in a set place every time

That depends on where the "set place" is. Generally speaking, you use `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` with `top bottom left right` to put an element in a very specific position.

> set the size to a specific size.

You do that with `width` and `height` and using whatever units give you what you're looking for. `px em % vh vw`, etc.